# Dijkstra: how to set a termination condition when finding the destination?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

As we know, Dijkstra finds the shortest path from a single source node to any other node in a given graph. I try to modify the original Dijkstra to find the shortest path between a pair of the source node and destination node. It seems easy that only set a termination condition for terminating the program when the Dijkstra finds the destination node.
**However, the "termination condition" I set in my Python codes seems to lead a sub-optimal shortest path rather than the optimal shortest path.**
The Dijkstra code is as follows,

```
def dijkstra(adjList, source, sink):
#define variables
n = len(adjList)    #intentionally 1 more than the number of vertices, keep the 0th entry free for convenience
visited = [False]*n
parent = [-1] *n
#distance = [float('inf')]*n
distance = [1e7]*n
heapNodes = [None]*n
heap = FibonacciHeap()
for i in range(1, n):
    heapNodes[i] = heap.insert(1e7, i)

distance[source] = 0
heap.decrease_key(heapNodes[source], 0)

while heap.total_nodes:
    current = heap.extract_min().value
    #print("Current node is: ", current)
    visited[current] = True
    #early exit
    if sink and current == sink:
        break
    for (neighbor, cost) in adjList[current]:
        if not visited[neighbor]:
            if distance[current] + cost < distance[neighbor]:
                distance[neighbor] = distance[current] + cost
                heap.decrease_key(heapNodes[neighbor], distance[neighbor])
                    if  neighbor == sink and current != source:     # this is a wrong logic , since the neighbor may not be selected as the next hop.
                            print("find the sink 1")
                            printSolution(source, sink, distance,parent)
                            break
    if neighbor == sink:
        print("find the sink2")
        break
return distance

adjList = [
[],
[[2, 7], [3, 9], [6, 14]],
[[1, 7], [4, 15], [3, 10]],
[[1, 9], [2, 10], [4, 11], [6, 2]],
[[2, 15], [3, 11], [5, 6]],
[[4, 6], [6, 9]],
[[5, 9], [1, 14]]
]
dijkstra(adjList,1,4)
```

The graph of the adjacency list is as shown:
[image]

I want to find the path from node 1 to node 4, there are three paths:

```
 path 1: 1 --> 2 --> 4              cost: 22
 path 2: 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4        cost: 28  
 path 3: 1 --> 3 --> 4              cost: 20
 path 4: 1 --> 3 --> 6 --> 5 --> 4  cost: 26
 path 5: 1 --> 6 --> 3 --> 4        cost: 28
 path 6: 1 --> 6 --> 5 --> 4        cost: 29
```

Originally, Dijkstra will select path 3: 1 --> 3 --> 4 since it has the minimum cost.

But, I modify the termination condition, i.e., when finding the adjacency node of the current node is the destination, the program will be ended. And I get the result of a path between node 1 and node 4. The result is path 1: 1 --> 2 --> 4.
I analyze that, this is because I set the wrong termination condition. The program will be terminated when finding the adjacency node of the current node is the destination, that is wrong but I have no idea that setting a proper termination condition when the destination node is found.Could you please provide some ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only right place for the termination condition is at the start of the outer loop when you just got the current node from the heap.

It is wrong to do that test when you iterate the neighbors, as you don't have the guarantee that this last edge is part of the shortest path. Just imagine some insane high cost for that last step to the neighbor: never could that be on the shortest path, so don't perform the terminating condition there: there still might be another path to the sink that is cheaper.

I also did not see where you actually populated `parent` in your code.

I would also not put all nodes on the heap from the start, as heaps are faster when they have fewer elements. You can start with a heap with just 1 node.

Another little optimisation is to use `parent` also for marking nodes as visited, so you don't actually need both `parent` and `visited`.

Finally, I don't know the `FibonacciHeap` library, so I have just taken `heapq`, which is a very light heap implementation:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def dijkstra(adjList, source, sink):
    n = len(adjList)
    parent = [None]*n
    heap = [(0, source, 0)] # No need to push all nodes on the heap at the start
    # only add the source to the heap

    while heap:
        distance, current, came_from = heappop(heap)
        if parent[current] is not None:  # skip if already visited
            continue
        parent[current] = came_from  # this also marks the node as visited
        if sink and current == sink:  # only correct place to have terminating condition
            # build path
            path = [current]
            while current != source:
                current = parent[current]
                path.append(current)
            path.reverse()
            return distance, path
        for (neighbor, cost) in adjList[current]:
            if parent[neighbor] is None:  # not yet visited
                heappush(heap, (distance + cost, neighbor, current))

adjList = [
[],
[[2, 7], [3, 9], [6, 14]],
[[1, 7], [4, 15], [3, 10]],
[[1, 9], [2, 10], [4, 11], [6, 2]],
[[2, 15], [3, 11], [5, 6]],
[[4, 6], [6, 9]],
[[5, 9], [1, 14]]
]
dist, path = dijkstra(adjList,1,4)
print("found shortest path {}, which has a distance of {}".format(path, dist))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that helps me a lot. I perform this code, it performs nicely with the input of "dijkstra(adjList,1,4)" which means it can find the shortest path between node 1 and node 4 while terminating the program properly.
However, when I change the input as "dijkstra(adjList,1,5)", i.e., find the shortest path between node 1 and node 5. This program gives the result "found shortest path [1, 3, 4, 5], which has a distance of 26". But the shortest path is [1,3,6,5] with a distance of 20.
Looking forward to your ideas, thank you in advance!

Comment: I found a solution to address the issue summarized in my last post. Just slightly revise @trincot codes,
1.heap = [(source,0,0)]  ——> heap = [(0,source,0)]
2. current, distance, came_from = heappop(heap) ——> distance, current, came_from = heappop(heap)
3. heappush(heap, (neighbor, distance + cost, current))  ——> heappush(heap, (distance + cost, neighbor,  current))
The reseason is that heappop should pop the minimum distance from the heap.

Comment: Good that you found the correction! Of course, the heap should get the distance as sort-key. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have the correct condition for exit in your code that is when current==sink. You cannot impose any other exit condition. The algorithm necessarily needs to run until the destination node is visited because only at this point you can fix the value of the shortest path to the destination. Because of this condition, the complexity of finding the single source single destination shortest path is the same as that of the single source all nodes shortest paths. So your early exit condition is correct and you should remove all the neighbor condition checks.